# Same result for openssl_encrypt and mcrypt_encrypt (MCRYPT_CAST_128)

Tags: php

I have old PHP project where used **mcrypt_encrypt**
But this function doesn't work in new PHP.
I try to convert it to php7+, use **openssl_encrypt**, but I got **no** same result, what I do wrong? 
Maybe do you know other way to get same result?

**mcrypt_encrypt function:**

```
public static function cryptToCode($data)
{

        $iv_size    = @mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_CAST_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv         = @mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM );
        $code       = @mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_CAST_128, self::KEY_TRANSLATE_ID, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
        $code       = bin2hex($code);

        return      $code;
}
```

**openssl_encrypt function:**

```
public static function cryptToCodeSSL($data, $key = self::KEY_TRANSLATE_ID, $method = "cast-128-ecb") //"cast-128-ecb"
{
        $iv_size    = openssl_cipher_iv_length($method);
        $iv         = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($iv_size);
        $code       = openssl_encrypt($data, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        $code       = bin2hex($code);

        return      $code;
}
```

Done:

I found library http://www.gilfether.com/phpcrypt/
I got same result.

Comment: `I got no same result` when you use a random IV, the results of the encryption should always be different.  Which is sort of the point of the IV.  What maters is if you can decrypt it, not if the cypertext is the same.

Comment: This encrypted string used for file path. I need know only encrypted string and I can not change file structure.

Comment: Interesting, why not use something easier such as a Hash algorithm (md5, sha etc.).  Hashes will always return the same value.  Sometimes I use `hash_file` for the file name, which hashes the contents.  It also works as a duplicate check if you need that.